# Application doesn't see high density's images

Tags: android

My project contains three drawable's folders: drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi and drawable. I build it with `android:minSdkVersion="3"`. When it runs on Andriod 1.6 or higher it always uses images from drawable-mdpi on high density screens.

**How to fix this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting `android:anyDensity="true"`?
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html